# Apply Symbology from Layer in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, symbology, arcgis-10.3

I have a model in ModelBuilder that takes a shapefile, runs some tools on it, adds it to a geodatabase, applies symbology from a layer file and converts it to a KMZ.  It all works fine except for the "Apply Symbology from Layer" tool.

I created a smaller model for testing the problem sections which is shown below.  The original input feature class is a geodatabase.  When I run this model, it runs and says it completes successfully, however my symbology is not applied to the layer.
[image]

The Input Layer and Symbology Layer are both point files, so that should not be the problem.  When I manually import the Symbology Layer (outside of ModelBuilder), it displays fine, so I don't think it's an issue with the layer file.

---

I tried to revise my model based on suggestions from Mapperz and MollyS.  Here is my revised model and screenshots of the two Properties windows but I am still unable to get a KMZ with the symbology.  Any ideas what I am doing wrong?
[image]

Comment: Use 'Layer to KML' instead with the symbol preset.

Comment: @Mapperz Thanks, I did not know about the symbol preset.  I think I'm looking in the right place (per MollyS's answer below), but something is still not working right for me.  I posted some additional information in my question showing what I tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason you have to use the "Apply Symbology From Layer" tool? I usually do this through the context windows. You can set the layer symbology for the output "SurveyEvidencePoint" by right-clicking "SurveyEvidencePoint", selecting properties, and then setting the path to your layer file.

Comment: Thanks, I was unaware of these settings.  I found them but they are still not producing a KMZ with my layer symbology.  I posted some additional info in my question if you can take a look.  Thanks!

Comment: I figured out what was causing my problem.  I had done a join on my layer earlier in the model, so the field name in my table did not match that in my symbology layer.  I was able to fix this by adding a new field with the same name as my symbology layer and calculating it from the previously joined field.